# Assembly - cmp doesn't work

Tags: assembly, compare

I'm trying to replace an unicode string (its length is 8) in assembly with some other. The address of the string beginning increased by 0x10 and is stored in EDI. I know the string value, but its address is changing, so I can't replace it by address. I'm using Code Injection in Cheat Engine.
That code works:

```
alloc(newmem,4096)
label(returnhere)
label(originalcode)
label(exit)

newmem:

repe movsb
cmp edi,0341E340
jne originalcode
mov [edi-10],31
mov [edi-0E],32
mov [edi-0C],33
mov [edi-0A],34
mov [edi-08],35
mov [edi-06],36
mov [edi-04],37
mov [edi-02],38

originalcode:

jmp MSVCR120.memcpy+53

exit:
jmp returnhere

"MSVCR120.dll"+F20C:
jmp newmem
nop
nop
returnhere:
```

but that doesn't:

```
alloc(newmem,8192)
label(returnhere)
label(originalcode)
label(exit)

newmem:

repe movsb

cmp [edi-10],41
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-0E],42
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-0C],43
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-0A],44
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-08],45
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-06],46
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-04],47
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-02],48
jne originalcode

mov [edi-10],31
mov [edi-0E],32
mov [edi-0C],33
mov [edi-0A],34
mov [edi-08],35
mov [edi-06],36
mov [edi-04],37
mov [edi-02],38

originalcode:

jmp MSVCR120.memcpy+53

exit:
jmp returnhere

"MSVCR120.dll"+F20C:
jmp newmem
nop
nop
returnhere:
```

Of course both codes could be assembled, but the second one does nothing (it can't go through the comparison part).
I'm sure the values I compare are good, because I've set a breakpoint when edi is 0341E340. What's more, when I execute the first and the second code (together, to be sure the value is right) it also doesn't work. 
Cheat Engine treats constants as hex values (exactly what I want) and it doesn't understand if I write, for example, 0Ch. So how should I compare the values?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this assembled without complaints, what does it choose as default operand size here? Bytes? Dwords? Probably not words, that would be weird, but you seem to expect that

Comment: both codes are of poor quality. Add size modifiers, how you intended them to be, like `cmp [edi-10],byte 41` .. also you are using `0C`, that's not a number, either `0x0C` or `0Ch`, or whatever your assembler supports, but I haven't seen any with default hexa numbers without any prefix/suffix. Why don't you copy here some code that can be assembled?

Comment: I've edited my question and put some code that can be assembled.

Comment: so how does cheat engine assemble `cmp [edi-10],41`? Will it treat 41 as byte, or word, or dword? What is the content of the string, you want to detect? From your second example it looks like you expect at [edi-10] `DB 'A', ?, 'B', ?, 'C', ?, 'D', ?, 'E', ?, 'F', ?, 'G', ?, 'H', ?, ? (<- here points edi)`. BTW, it looks like the memcpy is done ahead of that, so instead you may patch `esi` to point to your constant, and let memcpy to copy that patched value into destination.

Comment: Just to make sure you understand the problem: `cmp [edi-10],byte 41` will test byte at address edi-10, if it is equal to `'A'`. `cmp [edi-10],dword 41` will test four bytes, starting at edi-10, if they are equal to `'A', 0, 0, 0` as dword 41 is `00000041` and x86 is little endian CPU. Maybe you can try `cmp [edi-10],00420041` to see, if it's assembled as dword? (if the content at edi-0F and edi-0D are `0` of course)

Comment: You were right. It tested four bytes, not one byte. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Cheat Engine was treating constants as 4 bytes, not 1 byte. I had to write it like:

```
cmp [edi-10],00320031
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-0C],00340033
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-08],00360035
jne originalcode
cmp [edi-04],00380037
jne originalcode
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`cmp edi,0341E340` compares value in edi (**no memory access**) with something, what was supposed to be hexadecimal constant, I guess.

`cmp [edi-10],41` compares value at address edi-10 (**content of memory**) with 41. From this instruction format it's not clear, whether byte or dword value is compared.

But in any case, the two are doing something completely different.

If you do for example:

```
; preparing test values + memory content for examples
mov edi,bufferAddress ; pointer to some writeable free memory
mov [edi],byte 41     ; all values are decimal
mov [edi+1],byte 1
; then these will evaluate as "equal" (ZF=1)
cmp edi,bufferAddress
cmp [edi],byte 41
cmp [edi],word 256+41  ; x86 little-endian
; these will evaluate as "not equal" (ZF=0)
cmp edi,bufferAddress+1
cmp [edi],word 41  ; on [edi+1] is "1" instead of 0
```

So it's completely confusing, why you even mix those two examples together.

Whether the second case works depends on the content of memory. Whether the first works depends on the value in `edi` (probably some buffer address).

Comment: Yes, 0341E340 is a content of EDI and it's an address where my string starts. The problem is, I can trace the address, but it's changing every time I run the program, so I can't hard-code it.